# How to terminate a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, kill

I'm working on a supercomputer and have a shell script that will automatically schedule a bunch of jobs for me. Once the script is run, I can terminate manually with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. I was running the script from a unix `screen` session and terminated the `screen`, but the script is somehow still running and submitting jobs. It seems to be stuck in a loop and not ending, thus consuming precious core-hours.

I tried `ps -u [user]` but it doesn't show up. I know for a fact that it's still running in the background and just need to kill it.

Edit: `uname -a` gives the following result:

```
Linux blogin3 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 19 21:14:45 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So I guess the supercomputer is running Linux.

Comment: What OS (or UNIX version) are you running this on.  What does `ps -ef | grep [scriptname]` show you?

Comment: Try `ps -f -u username`. Then `kill processid` or `kill -9 processid`

Comment: @EightBitTony @terdon I've edited the original post to reflect the new information. Also, `ps -ef | grep [scriptname]` gives something like this: `[user]     38875  34136  0 09:20 pts/3    00:00:00 grep [scriptname]`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The script name doesn't show up when I try `ps -f -u [username]`

Comment: It should show up if you run `ps aux | grep scriptname`.

Comment: Also, if it doesn't, please post the script. It might be that you're using a queue system and the script has added the jobs to the queue and has exited. That's why jobs are still being launched but you don't see the script itself. Another possibility is that you've connected to a different node on the server than you used last time. Depending on how the server is set up, it might assign sessions to nodes randomly.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to debug with the information you've provided but consider this:

```
$ cat foo.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true
do 
    echo yes; 
done
```

That's just a simple infinite loop. If I launch the script with `./foo.sh`, I can find it in the output of `ps`:

```
$ ps aux | grep foo.sh
terdon   25568  0.0  0.0  10996  1424 pts/12   S+   16:19   0:00 bash /home/terdon/scripts/foo.sh
terdon   25982  0.0  0.0  10356   928 pts/11   S+   16:23   0:00 grep --color foo.sh
```

To kill it, the simplest approach would be to use `pkill` and its `-f` flag:

```
   -f, --full
          The pattern is normally only matched against the  process  name.
          When -f is set, the full command line is used.
```

So, try:

```
pkill -f foo.sh
```

Comment: I run the script from the command line using `sh myscript.sh` but `ps aux | grep myscript.sh` comes up with nothing except this: `jdong     39034  0.0  0.0 103252   864 pts/3    S+   09:32   0:00 grep myscript.sh` where the time is the current time. And no matter what I put for the argument of `ps`, it will return something like that

Comment: @user1799323 that's very strange. Why are you so sure that the script is still running then? Also, you said "supercomputer", that can complicate things. Are you sure you've connected to the same node as your original session?